# Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на метку карты выведенный отдельно список элементов (коллекция), скроллился к нужному месту (соответстующему метке)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, map

Есть вопрос, как мне сделать так, чтобы при клике на метку список элементов, выведенный отдельно скроллился к нужному элементу (соответствующему). Это нужно так как список планируется в виде ограниченного по высоте блока поверх карты, а элементов будет много.

Вот пример - https://www.berryalloc.com/global/en/dealers

Тут список и точки «связаны»: кликая на метку скроллится к элементу внешнего списка, а кликая по элементу списка двигает к метке на карте и открывает балун

Answer (score 1):

## Скролл к элементу в списке по клику на метку

Для того, чтобы сопоставить выбранной метке нужный элемент списка, проставьте элементам дата аттрибут `id`, соответствующий `id` меток:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="element" data-id="1">г. Москва</li>
  <li class="element" data-id="2">г. Санкт-Петербург</li>
</ul>
```

Повесьте `click`-обработчик на метки на карте, в обработчике реализуйте скролл контейнера к нужному элементу: можете воспользоваться браузерным методом [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) или какой-нибудь сторонней библиотекой (например, [jump.js](https://github.com/callmecavs/jump.js)). Должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
eventsGroup.add(['click'], event => {
  // Получаем id метки, по которой произошел клик
  const pinId = event.get('objectId');

  // Находим нужный элемент в списке по id
  const list = document.querySelector('.list');
  const targetLi = list.querySelector(`[data-id='${pinId}']`);

  // Скролл к нужному элементу
  jump(targetLi);
});
```

Про события на карте можно почитать в [официальной документации API Яндекс.Карт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/events-docpage/)

## Выбор метки на карте по клику на элемент списка

Вешайте обработчик на список. Теперь по `id`, зашитому в data-атрибут элемента списка, нужно найти точку на карте и выделить ее, поменяв ее preset.

```
const list = document.querySelector('.list');

// Делегирование событий - вешаем один общий обработчик на весь список
list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches('li.element')) {
    const elementId = e.target.dataset.id;
    // Передаем id в метод перерисовки меток
    refreshObjects(elementId);
  }
});

// Метод для изменения внешнего вида меток
function refreshObjects(elementId) {
  // Перебираем все объекты на карте
  objectManager.objects.each(object => {
    const isActive = object.id === elementId;

    // Обновляем параметры метки по текущему id
    objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(object.id, {
      // Меняем пресет метки: используйте нужные вам пресеты из вашего проекта
      preset: isActive ? 'active-preset' : 'default-preset'
    }
  }
}
```